# Is there any way to sniff named pipe traffic in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes

Is there any tool that can monitor/capture/sniff named pipe traffic?

Even when max instance = 1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no official way.

Use [API hooking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed). Hook ReadFile and/or WriteFile, maybe also CreateFileA/W (assuming that the app is a pipe client) and do the necessary things on their invocation.

Microsoft has also its own library for API hooking - [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) .